# Disable blue border for selected Listview item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a ListView with Horizontal WrapPanel as its ItemsPanelTemplate.
I want to get rid of the blue background for selected item. It is visible only on the left of the selected item.

There are many similar question on SO and I tried a lot of the solutions and none of them worked.

This is what I have already tried:

```
<ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <!-- Foreground for Selected ListViewItem -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                             Color="Black"/>
                    <!-- Background for Selected ListViewItem -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Transparent"/>
                    <!--SelectedItem without focus-->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>



<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleSelectedItemDoubleClick"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" CenterX="12" CenterY="12" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="150"/>
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="210" Margin="15" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` for the `ListView` to be `Transparent` (or whatever color you want)

I typically put this in the `ListView.Resources` so it only applies to the specific `ListView`, and not all `ListViews` in my application

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                     Color="Transparent"/>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Its very close to what you have in your code already, but you need to set it for the `ListView.Resources`, not `ListViewItem.Resources`

Comment: This trick did nothing for me, but what worked was to disable FocusVisualStyle. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198580/remove-black-border-style-from-listview-selected-item) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all default styling (hovering, selecting, etc.) just define a custom Template for the ItemContainer (not the Item itself):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

[Found on MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeapps/en-US/6bc08ba3-88d5-4e13-9300-f54067ef3a5c/get-rid-of-the-damn-blue-selection-border#eb0014d5-ca9f-4228-a48f-b0d5cd8b049a)

Answer (score 0):

This is what did it for me:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" Width="185" MaxWidth="185">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock 
                Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Foreground="DarkGoldenrod" 
                            FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"
                            Text="{Binding Path=EventTypeName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Foreground="DarkGoldenrod"
                    FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"
                    Text="{Binding Path=AccountIdentity, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Foreground="DarkGoldenrod" MaxWidth="170"
                            FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Path=EventMessage,Mode=OneWay}"
                            Text="{Binding Path=EventMessage, Mode=OneWay}" />

            <TextBlock 
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                Foreground="Black" 
                                FontSize="8" 
                                Text="{Binding Path=EventLoggedOn, Mode=OneWay}"
                                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                ToolTip="{Binding Path=EventLoggedOn, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                Foreground="Black" 
                                FontSize="8"
                                Text="{Binding Path=QualifiedCreator, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightGray" Opacity="1" Width="185" MaxWidth="185">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock 
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Foreground="Yellow" 
                            FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"
                            Text="{Binding Path=EventTypeName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock
                            Background="Transparent"
                    Foreground="Yellow"
                    FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"
                    Text="{Binding Path=AccountIdentity, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Foreground="DarkGoldenrod" MaxWidth="170"
                            FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Path=EventMessage,Mode=OneWay}"
                            Text="{Binding Path=EventMessage, Mode=OneWay}" />

            <TextBlock 
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                Foreground="Black" 
                                FontSize="8" 
                                Text="{Binding Path=EventLoggedOn, Mode=OneWay}"
                                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                ToolTip="{Binding Path=EventLoggedOn, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                Foreground="Black" 
                                FontSize="8"
                                Text="{Binding Path=QualifiedCreator, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SelectedTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to set the background to {x:Null} when the item is selected, using a trigger.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                Value="{x:Null}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                                Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListView>
```

Comment: In that case, have you tried using Snoop or Wpf Inspector to have a look at the highlighted item and find out exactly which element has been highlighted? It's obviously not the ListViewItem but something else is being affected.