# Disable blue border for selected Listview item 2

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Edit: new topic here: [Do x:Static extensions work in WinRT-XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674526/xstatic-extension-doesnt-work-anymore)

I found this 
[Disable blue border for selected Listview item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297149/disable-blue-border-for-selected-listview-item)
but it does not working for me. I have some bug in  -> 
Error: "The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible."
Error 2: "The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'ListView'." 
Error 3: "'Unexpected 'ATTRIBUTE' in parse rule 'NonemptyPropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG.'.' Line number '11' and line position '29'."
Error 4: "The type 'x:Static' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built."

There is my code XAML:

```
<ListView.Resources x:Name="gui_listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="610" Margin="48,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="256" SelectionChanged="gui_listView_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

I really dont know what am i doing wrong, im not good in XAML, probably im doing some stupid mistake. Can someone write me, how it should be? Thank's for all response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the entire problem, but at least you need to put that XAML code block within `<ListView>` tag, and set attribute of the `<ListView>` as opposed to `<ListView.Resources>` :

```
<ListView x:Name="gui_listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="610" Margin="48,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="256" SelectionChanged="gui_listView_SelectionChanged" 
          SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                 Color="Transparent"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Still saying error number 4, but now its just about error with that x:Key=... Any ideas?
There is errors:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img835/4764/jlcc9.jpg

Comment: WinRT/metro apps doesn't support `x:Static` extension, it is for standard WPF desktop application project

Comment: Yea, i found this too. So, what now? :o I cant find anything.

Comment: that's a whole different question now. I'd suggest to open new question. Since I'm not well experienced in WinRT apps, can't help much on this matter

Comment: Good idea, ill do it. Thanks.

Comment: hi @GrowSing, I saw your new question. One suggestion, start with XAML from this answer as opposed to XAML in the question, so that people can focus only on fixing the `x:Static` part. Good luck