# Do x:Static extensions work in WinRT-XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Edit: This is continue of this topic:[Disable blue border for selected Listview item 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673464/disable-blue-border-for-selected-listview-item-2/23673682?noredirect=1#comment36369773_23673682)

I wanted to do this in app for Windows 8.1:

```
<ListView x:Name="gui_listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Height="610" Margin="48,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Width="256" SelectionChanged="gui_listView_SelectionChanged" 
      SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
             Color="Transparent"/>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

But microsoft probably ended support for static extension's. Anybody know what i should do now?
There is picture of errors, what i got.
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img835/4764/jlcc9.jpg

Thanks for any response.

Comment: are you assigning name, alignment and dimensions to `Resources` section?

Comment: I dont know what you mean..? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you really set things like `x:Name`, `HorizontalAlignment`, `Height` and so on against `ListView.Resources` or `ListView`? What you've pasted won't compile and not because error that you mention

Comment: This is continue of this topic: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673464/disable-blue-border-for-selected-listview-item-2/23673682?noredirect=1#comment36369773_23673682

Comment: I'm sorry, i pasted a wrong code, now it should be better.

Comment: So are you looking for WinRT solution? This code will work in WPF. If so why do you tag your question as WPF and not WindowsPhone for example?

Comment: Not, i'm writing it for windows 8.1, but tag 8.1 can be used, just if u have more than 15 reputation i thing.

Comment: What about `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}" Color="Transparent"/>`?

Comment: XIMIMAX - Same error. There is problem with that static thing (picture upper).

Comment: shouldn't you assign the `{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}` to the `Color` property?

Comment: I dont know and that is reason, why i asking. How could i do this? I'm really newbie on xaml...

Comment: like I said if you are trying to assign a SystemColour to your ListView then: In your `xaml` file click on your `ListView` in your Properties->Background->click on little square just after the name of the background property and select ApplyResource and then in the popup select desired colour. This should do the trick. HTH

Comment: That does not work. if i click on that square i just can click on custom ex., system res. and create data binding. I'm verry desperate... That ugly fuc*ing border if you select item in that list view is soooo anyoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked two questions in your question, I will provide both answers. To remove the mouse over effect, you need to override the theme value. You do this in app.xaml.

```
<Application
    x:Class="App41.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App41">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Here's the whole list embedded in the style itself:

```
<ListViewItemPresenter 
    CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" 
    CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" 
    ContentMargin="4" 
    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
    CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" 
    DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" 
    DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
    DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
    DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" 
    FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1" 
    PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
    PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
    ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
    SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" 
    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True" 
    SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" 
    SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
    SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}" 
    SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, but i still have one wierd border, that is visible just on mouse over, look at picture. 
http://i.imgur.com/dk0DYJr.jpg
Dont you know how can i remove him? It's last border (or whatever it is), what i need to remove...i hope so.

Comment: The is not the mouseover shadow, it is the selectedborder. I am amazed that it is visible when it is not selected on when mouseover. Are you sure you are not overriding another style somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The fact is `x:Static` hasn't stopped working, it never has worked in the Windows Runtime. All binding is to instance objects in Windows Runtime. I realize this is definitely different than WPF. But it is what it is, the easiest workaround is to wrap your static references in your view model.

```
public static class Information
{
    public static string Secret = "8675309";
}

public class MyViewModel 
{
    public string Secret { get { return Information.Secret; } }
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[MSDN ListView styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
put that in your `Window` or `UC` `Resources` tag.
Now locate `VisualState` which is responsible for highlighting and change it to your liking.
HTH
P.S. reason why I haven't posted ready solution is because you will benefit more  from finding out which part is responsible for highlighting and it will make the development easier.

Comment: I still dont know. I appreciate when you trying to learn me self-sufficiency, but i'm really newbie. Can you please me more describe way how can i do this? From my own experience i know, from code i will learn more. Is bad, if you copy some code and you either dont know which part what doing. If you describe me that way how i can do this in steps and maybe you explain me something i will be grateful. :))